# upload files in firebase via rest API

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, dart-null-safety

how do I upload files(images,pdf,mp3,mp4) in firebase via Rest API using flutter http package ??

I want to upload files from my phone to firebase and after uploaded get the url of upload file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the official [flutter storage package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage). You can then upload files as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files):

```dart
// Create a storage reference from our app
final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

// Create a reference to "mountains.jpg"
final mountainsRef = storageRef.child("mountains.jpg");

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String filePath = '${appDocDir.absolute}/file-to-upload.png';
File file = File(filePath);

try {
  await mountainsRef.putFile(file);
} on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
  // ...
}
```